# The key of Kafka is same to the value in Flink 1.15

Tags: apache-flink

Use the method "sinkTo" write the record to Kafka,but the key of  Kafka is same to the value in the result.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WLogd.png)

Comment: can you show your code to configure the kafka sink?

Comment: tanks,it has solved